# how to mention path in war file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I converted one java project into war file. In that java file there is a path=" System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\src\Configuration\Config.properties". Now I want to change the path, that will be suitable for war file. I am using jboss 5 server and eclipse. So anyone tell me how to change the path.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change in your source accordingly before export your war

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You have request object available with you then you can try following :

"request.getRequestURI()"

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but [request.getRequestURI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) retruns _Returns the part of this request's URL from the protocol name up to the query string in the first line of the HTTP request_ and it's not a absolute path to the source it's only part of the URL.

Comment: Correct It will return the URI from that URI you can construct relative path using that
String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());

Answer (score 0):

To obtain real path to a resource you can use [ServletContext.getRealPath(String path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)). But be aware that if your container doesn't unzip your war before using, you may receive *null*.  So, if you put your properties file into *your_app_in_war_root/config/config.properties* you will be able to get path to it by `ServletContext.getRealPath("config/config.properties")` , but be noticed that the properties can be achieved by `http://your_app_url/config/config.properties` in that case.

If your point is to load some properties when your application started you should try to use embedded properties management like [this from Spring](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/), I'm not sure but maybe [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Additional_Services-System_Properties_Management.html) is useful.

Comment: Hi i can't able to use the ServletContext in java page. Can you give suggestion please.

Comment: @balaguru Sorry, I didn't catch. Why are you can't? Do you want a solutions that works on both native app and web app?